# Box API, Unable to get sharedlink of a file. Shows Bad Request Error

Tags: box-api

```
BoxApi.V2.BoxManager boxManager = new BoxManager(response1.Data.access_token);
                       var sharedLink = new SharedLink()
                       {
                           Access = Access.Open,
                           Permissions = new Permissions() { CanDownload = true, CanPreview = true },
                           UnsharedAt = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
                       };
                       boxManager.ShareLink(file, sharedLink);
```

This below code throws "Bad request" error to me, can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify what type of account you have with Box?

If you have a personal account, removing

```
UnsharedAt = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
```

should allow the request to work.

Expiring shared links requires an upgraded account